# Does itunes and google play pay to free application?

Tags: google-play, itunes

I have developed two applications for both android and iphone. I am going to launch both application to google play and itunes, I just want to know that does google play and itunes pay to free application for per download or something else. Please let me know if somebody knows about that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store policies.

Answer (score 0):

No one will pay you for free applications but if you put banners inside your app, you will earn something with them.